# Java: Execute shell script with mysql command via java code

Tags: java, mysql, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script from my java code.
The shell script contains a mysql statement.
The response from the console is that the command can not be found.

The script works perfectly fine if no mysql command is in the shell script. I can execute the shell script from the command line without any problems. 
There must be a problem within java.

My Java code:

```
try {
     String[] cmd = { "sh", "./shellScript/shellScript.sh" };
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
     p.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u "..user.." "-p..p.." "..db.." < "file.sql" > output.txt
```

I expected the file to be executed, but the console was returning the command:

```
./shellScript/shellScript.sh: line 3: mysql: command not found
```

Comment: I 'mysql' command available to execute from your terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can execute mysql commands in the terminal. It only does not run if the shell script is executed by java runtime. How can I make sure that the mysql command is known when the shell script is executed from the java runtime.